# MLE for two independent factor CIR

Tags: interest-rates, vasicek

Following the maximun likelihood estimation as done in   [Klavidko](http://dsp.vscht.cz/konference_matlab/MATLAB07/prispevky/kladivko_k/kladivko_k.pdf) I would like to generalize this to more independent  factors . In first istance I would use the transition function at time t as a sum of the non chi squared conditional distributions for each factor:
\begin{equation}
p_t = p_{1 t} +.. + p_{N t}
\end{equation}
then take the log of the product of all t times used in the data and optimize: 
\begin{equation}
L = \sum_{t}log(p_t)
\end{equation}
On the other hand in the paper [multi](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAEahUKEwiI846Yj8jIAhXIpB4KHdg5AWU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.504.6833%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNEqebJd0l270WdWh9BvDmpmzpg6XA%22%22) they just optimize the sum of each log product 
\begin{equation}
L = \sum_{t,i}log(p_{i t})
\end{equation}
Which one is correct?
Thanks